# How to change link url when clicking each tab with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change URL link (in browser and in ) when I click each tab with jquery, but I cant. URL should take ID of .vertical-tab-content-container

My HTML code is:

```
<div class="vertical-tabs">
   <a href="" class="js-vertical-tab vertical-tab is-active" rel="tab1">Applications</a>
   <a href="" class="js-vertical-tab vertical-tab" rel="tab2">Web Applications</a>
   <a href="" class="js-vertical-tab vertical-tab" rel="tab3">Portals</a>
   <a href="" class="js-vertical-tab vertical-tab" rel="tab4">Applications</a>
</div>  
<div class="vertical-tab-content-container">
   <div id="tab1" class="js-vertical-tab-content vertical-tab-content">
      <p>Content 1</p>
   </div>
   <div id="tab2" class="js-vertical-tab-content vertical-tab-content">
      <p>Content 2</p>
   </div>
   <div id="tab3" class="js-vertical-tab-content vertical-tab-content">
      <p>Content 3</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.vertical-tab-content').each(function() {
var id = $(".vertical-tab-content").attr('id');
});

$(".vertical-tabs .vertical-tab").each(function(){ 
  $(this).click(function(){
    window.location.hash  = $(this)[0].id;
  });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by changing the link url? You want to update the href of the `a` tags or do you want to show the respective `tab contents` ?

Comment: For example <a href="" class="js-vertical-tab vertical-tab is-active" rel="tab1">Applications</a> should take a href="tab1" class="js-vertical-tab vertical-tab is-active" rel="tab1">Applications</a>. Dynamically should change each <a href ... >

Comment: $("a").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/"); you can simply trie this on click event and can also add it  in this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there's no need for the first loop in your actual code, in the second loop you can profit from the `index` in the callback function.

This is how should be your code:

```
$(".vertical-tabs .vertical-tab").each(function(i){ 
  $(this).click(function(e){
    $(this).attr("href", $('.vertical-tab-content')[i].id);
    window.location.hash  = $('.vertical-tab-content')[i].id;
  });
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(".vertical-tabs .vertical-tab").each(function(i){ 
  $(this).click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(i);
    $(this).attr("href", $('.vertical-tab-content')[i].id)
    //window.location.hash  = $('.vertical-tab-content')[i].id;
    console.log($('.vertical-tab-content')[i].id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vertical-tabs">
   <a href="" class="js-vertical-tab vertical-tab is-active" rel="tab1">Applications</a>
   <a href="" class="js-vertical-tab vertical-tab" rel="tab2">Web Applications</a>
   <a href="" class="js-vertical-tab vertical-tab" rel="tab3">Portals</a>
</div>  
<div class="vertical-tab-content-container">
   <div id="tab1" class="js-vertical-tab-content vertical-tab-content">
      <p>Content 1</p>
   </div>
   <div id="tab2" class="js-vertical-tab-content vertical-tab-content">
      <p>Content 2</p>
   </div>
   <div id="tab3" class="js-vertical-tab-content vertical-tab-content">
      <p>Content 3</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, you just need to add this: `$(this).attr("href", $('.vertical-tab-content')[i].id)`, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attaching events to each DOM element individually, it would be better if you use `Event Delegation` i.e., attaching event to the parent element and then verifying if the element clicked is desired element or not and then taking the appropriate action.

In your case, you can check for `js-vertical-tab` class and then change the `href` of the `target` element by using `rel` attribute

```js
$('.vertical-tabs').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(e.target.classList.contains('js-vertical-tab')) {
    e.target.href = e.target.rel;
    console.log(e.target.href);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vertical-tabs">
   <a href="" class="js-vertical-tab vertical-tab is-active" rel="tab1">Applications</a>
   <a href="" class="js-vertical-tab vertical-tab" rel="tab2">Web Applications</a>
   <a href="" class="js-vertical-tab vertical-tab" rel="tab3">Portals</a>
   <a href="" class="js-vertical-tab vertical-tab" rel="tab4">Applications</a>
</div>  
<div class="vertical-tab-content-container">
   <div id="tab1" class="js-vertical-tab-content vertical-tab-content">
      <p>Content 1</p>
   </div>
   <div id="tab2" class="js-vertical-tab-content vertical-tab-content">
      <p>Content 2</p>
   </div>
   <div id="tab3" class="js-vertical-tab-content vertical-tab-content">
      <p>Content 3</p>
   </div>
</div>
```